# Getting custom class type returning functions on the Datasnap client autogenerated methods

Tags: server, client, delphi-xe, datasnap

I am using a TDSServerModule in which I place the functions needed.
When I create the TDSAdminClient with the wizard, I get the autogenerated functions from the TDSServerModule, but not all of them.
Some of the functions need a result types of my custom classes

```
  TStringArray = array of string;
  TStringArrayOfString = array of TStringArray;
  TStringArrayOfArrayOfString = array of TStringArrayOfString;
```

Those functions are not autogenerated. I changed the result type of them as TObject in order to get the autogenerated ones in the client side. 
Then I changed the type to my custom type again in client and server, but the server does not recognize them any way.

How can this be solved?